# Getting older balances of users from system with ~10 millions of users and txns, after filtering who were inactive, i.e. did not have any txns

Tags: mysql, optimization, data-retrieval

This looks like more of a db.stackexchange question, but putting here as there could be scripting solutions as well. Please pardon the lack of structure in framing the question.

Tables involved -

**Account**

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(14) NOT NULL,
  `acc_complete_id` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uuid_UNIQUE` (`uuid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_id_UNIQUE` (`account_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `acc_complete_id_UNIQUE` (`acc_complete_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Transaction**

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `debit` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debit_bal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `credit_bal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `transaction_credit_index` (`credit`),
  KEY `transaction_debit_index` (`debit`),
  KEY `transaction_created_index` (`created`),
  KEY `transaction_ref_index` (`ref`),
  KEY `transaction_narrative_index` (`narrative`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Table columns**

- debit_bal and credit_bal are balances of both the accounts involved in txn, after the txn.

We currently find the total number of inactive users with zero balances (inactivity based on who have
not transacted in between a certain period. 
But now, the painful part is, we need to get this data for some past months (inactivity during that time and account balances du)

Query being used currently to fetch count of inactive users with zero balance and some conditions on created date, type, etc. -

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT( a.uuid )),
  Sum(a.balance) 
FROM
  account a 
WHERE
  a.balance = 0.00 and a.type = "1" 
  AND a.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' 
  AND 
  (
    a.account_id + 100000000000 
  )
  NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.debit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.debit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' 
      )
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.credit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.credit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' 
      )
  )
```

Above query returns the count of inactive users with balance in approx 10 mins.

Inactive users = Users - (Set of users who have done debit UNION users who have done credit).

However, I cannot run this query for older months, because the value that I would get would be based on current balances and those were not same then. Account types also might have not been same, but we found those and updated in a duplicate table.

Now, when I try to get the inactive users count, along with present balances, by removing the count() and adding a group by uuid in the end, the query runs for more than 15 hours, and mysql thread state shows shows "removing duplicates" for most of the time.

Explain output -

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type        | possible_keys                                                                            | key                              | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a          | NULL       | ALL         | PRIMARY,uuid_UNIQUE,account_id_UNIQUE,acc_complete_id_UNIQUE,created_index,updated_index | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL | 23745634 |     5.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pt         | NULL       | ref_or_null | transaction_debit_index,transaction_created_index                        | transaction_debit_index  | 9       | func |       32 |     7.52 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pa         | NULL       | eq_ref      | account_id_UNIQUE,created_index                                                          | account_id_UNIQUE                | 8       | func |        1 |     5.00 | Using index condition; Using where           |
|  4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | pt         | NULL       | ref_or_null | transaction_credit_index,transaction_created_index                       | transaction_credit_index | 9       | func |       22 |     7.52 | Using where                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | pa         | NULL       | eq_ref      | account_id_UNIQUE,created_index                                                          | account_id_UNIQUE                | 8       | func |        1 |     5.00 | Using index condition; Using where           |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union2,4> | NULL       | ALL         | NULL                                                                                     | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL |     NULL |     NULL | Using temporary                              |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I need to get the list of users, which is taking a lot of time -

```
       SELECT DISTINCT
( a.uuid ),
  Sum(a.balance) 
FROM
  account a 
WHERE
  a.type = "1" 
  AND a.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' 
  AND 
  (
    a.account_id + 100000000000 
  )
  NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.debit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.debit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59'
      )
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.credit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.credit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59'
      )
  )
GROUP BY
  a.id;
```

It takes almost 15 hours and still continues. This is too long because I need to do this for several months and any error means I need to run again.

**Some sample data**

Some sample data -

Account table -

```
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id   | account_id | acc_complete_id | uuid                | last_updated        | created             | balance |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|   29 |      50536 |    100000050536 | 1026651502611722400 | 2020-01-09 12:43:49 | 2018-01-01 00:00:01 | 2092.10 |
| 1337 |      53071 |    100000053071 | 7266704751953077361 | 2019-12-26 11:45:54 | 2019-10-22 18:13:21 |   99.00 |
|   30 |      50673 |    100000050673 | 8799857402485889540 | 2020-01-05 13:21:16 | 2017-01-01 00:00:01 | 2166.10 |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Transaction

```
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| id      | created             | amount | debit        | credit       | debit_bal | credit_bal |
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 2001705 | 2019-12-07 14:14:18 |   1.00 | 100000050536 |            3 |   2092.00 | 2332445.91 |
| 2001869 | 2020-05-08 14:29:00 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2088.10 |       4.00 |
| 2001874 | 2020-05-09 14:45:04 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2084.10 |       8.00 |
| 2001875 | 2020-05-09 14:46:37 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2080.10 |      12.00 |
| 2002018 | 2019-11-29 18:05:41 |  50.00 | 100000053071 | 300000050673 |      0.00 |    2170.10 |
| 2002019 | 2019-11-29 18:07:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 | 300000050673 |    100.00 |    2170.10 |
| 2002020 | 2019-11-29 18:07:56 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002021 | 2019-11-29 18:15:22 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002022 | 2019-11-29 18:18:45 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002023 | 2019-11-29 18:20:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002024 | 2019-11-29 18:24:18 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002025 | 2019-11-29 18:26:19 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002026 | 2019-11-29 18:28:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002027 | 2019-11-29 18:29:37 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002028 | 2019-11-29 18:30:40 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002029 | 2019-11-29 18:35:55 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002030 | 2019-11-29 18:42:16 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002031 | 2019-12-02 13:12:01 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002032 | 2019-12-02 13:18:21 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002033 | 2019-12-02 13:27:53 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002034 | 2019-12-02 13:38:11 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |     99.00 |  580038.00 |
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

**Summarizing**

- So, I have to get the list of users with their current balances from here. This is the bottleneck and I am unable to think of breaking down this part to deduce the final result.
- Once I have the list of such users with current balances, I can query another table of total debit and credit txns against each user in subsequent months, and thereafter, do some addition and subtraction to arrive at the old balances of each user and then add them up to find all such users. There are hardly double digit number of users in a given month with txns, so that part happens fast.

I am now thinking about alternatives to get the data. 
Note that we have isolated these tables and there is no live traffic now, so we can add more indexes if needed.

I do not have a lot of time to experiment a lot of approaches, but what I am thinking of next is to add flag fields to the account table, like "nov_inactive", "dec_inactive" etc. denoting where a user was inactive during that month. I guess trying to update a duplicate table using the same selection criteria would also take similar time -

```
update
  account_copy 
set
  nov_updates = 
  (
    1
  )
WHERE
  a.type = "1" 
  AND a.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' 
  AND 
  (
    a.account_id + 100000000000 
  )
  NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.debit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.debit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59'
      )
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
( pt.credit ) 
    FROM
      transaction pt 
    WHERE
      pt.created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59' 
      AND MOD(pt.credit, 100000000000) IN 
      (
        SELECT
          pa.account_id 
        FROM
          account pa 
        WHERE
          pa.type = "1" 
          AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59'
      )
  )
GROUP BY
  a.id;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are acc_complete_id, type, and balance relevant to this problem?

Comment: Is "user" the same as `account`?  Why is there no `account_id` in `transactions`?  That is, how can I decide if a user has no transactions in a certain time?

Comment: @RickJames user is same as account. Transaction table's credit/debit columns links to Users table, depending on which user was involved with the credit and which to debit.

Comment: @Strawberry the acc_complete_id is 1<zero padding>account_id. For querying account_id is used, so you can ignore this and the type as well. Balance is the field which is important, as using the current balance against each user, we can deduce the old balance and if that is zero, we can consider that user as a zero balance user. Finding the total number of users with zero balances as on an older month is the target, and for that I am trying to find the mapping of inactive users with their current balance first.

Comment: So, `debit_balance` is the user's balance, where "user" is determined by the user id given in `debit`.  (Sorry, we should not have to ask this many questions about the meaning of the columns; consider changing the names and/or adding comments in the `CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: @RickJames noted. debit_balance and credit_balance are balances of users after the txn.

Comment: `MOD(pt.debit, 100000000000)` smells like a performance stumbling block; what is going on?

Comment: @RickJames, we figured out a solution. There are account IDs in the account table which are the remainders of the debit and credit fields in txn table. That is why the mod. E.g. if account_id is 12345678, debit/credit would be 100012345678.

Comment: @SandeepanNath - Please share the solution for the sake of the dozens of onlookers.  (Or delete the question.)  The "mod" sounds like a clumsy kludge; have you figured out how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we calculated the old balance -

```
select count(account_id), sum(if(temp2.old_balance is null,temp1.balance, temp2.old_balance)) 
from
         (
          select 
           pa.account_id, pa.balance, temp.acc_id as acc_id from account as pa force index (created_index)
           left join
                   ((select mod(debit,100000000000) as acc_id from transaction where created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59') 
                                  union 
                     (select mod(credit,100000000000) as acc_id from transaction where created BETWEEN '2018-02-28 18:29:59' AND '2019-11-30 18:29:59')
                    ) as temp
           on pa.account_id=temp.acc_id
           where pa.type = '1' AND pa.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59'
           having acc_id is null
          )
  as temp1
  left join 
  (
      select temp.acc_id,temp.txn_amt,b.balance,(b.balance-temp.txn_amt) as old_balance from  
      (
         select mod(temp.acc_id,100000000000) as acc_id, sum(if(type=1,temp.amount,0-temp.amount)) as txn_amt from 
         (
              select credit as acc_id,sum(amount) as amount, '1' as type from transaction where created > '2019-11-30 18:29:59' and status= "SUCCESSFUL" group by credit 
              UNION
              select debit as acc_id, sum(amount) as amount, '0' as type from transaction where created > '2019-11-30 18:29:59' and status= "SUCCESSFUL" group by debit
          ) as temp group by temp.acc_id
      ) as temp join account as b on temp.acc_id=b.account_id where b.created <= '2018-02-28 18:29:59' and type='1'
   ) as temp2 
   on temp1.account_id=temp2.acc_id
```

In the temp1 alias, we get the current balance and in temp2 alias we get the old balance of those users who transacted after the report month.